# Pass form to template after registration

Tags: django

I'm using django-registration app to perform registration. After registration (no matter if successful or not), I'd like to return to whatever page the registation app would redirect, **but** I want to pass a login form to that template.

Something like this:

```
def register(request):
    registered = reg_views.register(request, backend='registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend', template_name='zzz/index.html')
    login_form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render_to_response(registered, { 'login_form': login_form })
```

and then in the template have the ussual:

```
{{ login_form.as_p }}
```

Here's what I am trying to achieve:
I want to leverage the functionality of the registration app. However, after a (un)successful registration, I need to be able to display the login form on the page. This login form should be passed from the view (DRY principle).

Thanks,
Matyas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^accounts/', include('external.registration.urls')),
)
```

*new urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^accounts/register', 'point.to.new.view'),
     (r'^accounts/', include('external.registration.urls')),
)
```

With this set, you can copy the register view somewhere on your code from the registration app, and modify it as you please, without having to modify the app it self. The register view is pretty straight forward so you will have no problem making some changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be needed to copy any code from `register` view of `django-registration`.

Say, you want to handle authentication functionality in your app named `accounts`

This goes in `accounts/views.py`

```
def registration_complete(request):
    login_form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render_to_response("registration_complete.html", {"login_form": login_form})
```

`accounts/urls.py`

```
url(r'^registration_complete/', 'accounts.views.registration_complete', name='accounts_registration_complete'),
```

In your template `registration_complete.html`

```
{{login_form.as_p}}
```

Now you are done with `registration_complete` setup.

`register` view of `django-registration` takes a `success_url` where it redirects after successful registration.

Provide this `success_url` as the url we created in accounts.

Your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^registration/register/$', 'registration.register', {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend', 'success_url': 'accounts_registration_complete'}),
    (r'^registration/', include('registration.urls')),
)
```

Now after registration the user will be redirected to a page which contains the login form.